# BTRFS resize - free space not available to use

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs, shrink

I'm trying to shrink BTRFS partition and create new EXT4 partition with that free space.

I did `btrfs filesystem resize -5g /`

Now I have this (notice Device slack equals what I shrinked):

```
orangepiplus2e:~:# btrfs device usage /
/dev/mmcblk2p2, ID: 1
   Device size:            14.15GiB
   Device slack:            5.00GiB
   Data,single:             7.66GiB
   Metadata,single:       768.00MiB
   System,single:          32.00MiB
   Unallocated:           725.00MiB
```

How can I free that 5 GB of Device slack to use? Google didn't help me out.

Comment: btrfs only resizes the file system, not the partition. You need to resize the partition as well.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question, post it as an answer instead and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gerald Schneider is right. I had to resize partition too. Thank you!

```
parted /dev/mmcblk2
(parted) resizepart
Partition number? 2
End?  [15.5GB]? 9.9GB
```